# Http POST leads to : Too many arguments to return

Tags: post, go

I'm having some troubles trying to execute a `POST` using `Golang`. With the code below

```
func Postfunc(w http.ResponseWriter , rep *http.Request) {
     var jsonStr = []byte(`{"id":"10012"}`)
     req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "url", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
     req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/Text")
     client := &http.Client{}
     resp, err := client.Do(req)
     if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }
     fmt.Println("responce Status:", resp.Status)
     fmt.Println("responce Headers:", resp.Header)
     defer resp.Body.Close()
     bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
     fmt.Println("responce Body:", string(bodyText))
     p := string(bodyText)
     return  p
}
```

I get the following error:

`too many arguments to return, have (string), want ()`

**What does this error mean? How can I fix this?**

Comment: So go to line 62 and you are calling a function that doesn't return anything, but you are doing `x = func()` or `x := func()`

Comment: Apart from @Adrian's correct answer, you are using `"url"` inside `NewRequest`. I don't know if that's intentional or not. Another thing, you should check if the status of your request is `200` by adding before `bodyText, err . . .` something like `if resp != 200 { fmt.Println("Received invalid response ...") } `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly right. Your function signature is:

```
func Postfunc(w http.ResponseWriter , rep *http.Request)
```

It has no return values. Therefore, your last line:

```
return  p
```

Has too many arguments, which would be any arguments at all. If you want to write text to the HTTP response, use the `ResponseWriter`:

```
w.Write(bodyText)
```